# Angular 1.x component bindings don't update after logging out and logging back in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular1.6

I've got a weird edge case scenario regarding Angular 1.x component bindings on an application with really poor front-end architecture.

I have a base controller called searchController, and all its child components are elements on searchController.html. On searchController.html there are five components and three hard-coded tabs for "people", "places", and "things". You can execute a search via several search modals or clicking on one of the tabs. Clicking on a tab executes a search and by default, we land on the people tab.

When I log in to the application and perform a search, all the child component bindings update. When I hard refresh and perform a search, all the child component bindings update. However, when I log out and subsequently log back in and perform a search, the bindings do not update. However, when I click on another tab, then a search executes and the binding DO update. The issue is not the modals as the information is passed from the modal to the searchController file.

I'd like any leads on solving this issue, because any radical changes will hurt an already brittle application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to try the following. We can use the DOM manipulation with the angular techniques like this.

```
    var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#YOUR_ELEMENT'));
    element.html('HTML_CHANGES');
```

This will not break up your existing functionality and If you can put this in to a separate service class then we are still keeping the angular base concepts as well like this.

```
     angular.module('YOUR_APP').factory('UIServices', function () {
        return {
           changeViewAfterLogin: function () {
              var ele = angular.element(document.querySelector('YOUR_ELEMENT'));
              ele.toggleClass('HTML_CHANGES');
           },
     }
```

And try to call this service function inside your controller and do what ever you want.